# Why is this regular expression matching so much?

Tags: regex

I am trying to use http://www.regexr.com/ to create a regular expression.

Basically I am looking to replace something that matches `<Openings>any other tags/text</Openings>`

```
<Openings><opening><item><x>3</x><y>3</y><width>10.5</width><height>13.5</height><type>rectangle</type><clipX>0</clipX><clipY>0</clipY><imgsrc></imgsrc></item></opening></Openings>
```

I started with `([\<Openings\>])\w+` (http://regexr.com/393mv ) but it seems to be matching too many things. Right now that regular expression should only match `<Openings>`.

Comment: Because you use `[]`. When you write `[hello]`, your regex engine will interprete it as "any character between the brackets", i.e. it will match any character that is either an h, e, l or o. If you want to match exact word or sentences, just remove the brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex to match the whole Openings tag is,

```
<Openings>.*?<\/Openings>
```

If you want to capture the contents inside the Openings tag then try the below,

```
<Openings>(.*?)<\/Openings>
```

Comment: I would think the more useful expression would have the ( ) around the .*? not around the tag itself?

Comment: but he don't want the text between the tags. He wants to match the whole.

Comment: @AvinashRaj She presumably wants the inside contents, regardless of the actual question.

Comment: he wants to match the tag (from opening openings tag to close openings tag.)

Comment: Why do you insist on the male pronoun for a female name?  Anyway, matching the whole thing is fine, but your original answer matched only the tag and not the contents, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: you mean this `<Openings>.*?<\/Openings>`?

Comment: It matches the whole Openings tag in a large html file.

Answer (score 0):

```
([\<Openings\>])\w+
```

The brackets mean "Match *any* character in this".  You should use

```
(\<Openings\>)\w+
```

which matches specifically `"<Openings>"` plus one or more word characters.

Comment: I only want it to match until </Openings> I don't want it to match anything before or after <Openings></Openings>